# How to force Visual Studio to use a specific framework version

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-directives

I have a class library that targets multiple frameworks.

i.e.

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>
```

When msbuild builds my application it correctly spits out both netstandard2.0 and netstandard2.1 assemblies.  I'm using precompile directives to include framework-specific code in the solution:

```
#if NETSTANDARD2_1
```

Visual Studio seems to choose to define `NETSTANDARD2_0`, but I can't figure out how to force it to use `NETSTANDARD2_1` instead.  The code within the `NETSTANDARD2_1` precompile directive is always grayed out.

[image]

Comment: It depends on your client application, that determines your framework
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

Comment: @Brian so, whichever project I have setup as my startup project?  I have a .NET Core 2.2 client app and a .NET Core 3.0 client app.

Comment: @Matt See my answer on the question I linked to. VS will always spit out both sets of binaries unless you target only one framework, but you can switch between the frameworks in VS so that your greyed out code becomes active.

Comment: Yes, just read through that and it answers my questions.  This is a duplicate.

Comment: @MattRuwe  yes, the client app or startup app sets the Target Framework.

Comment: @Brian FYI, I tried to change the startup project and that didn't change the framework version selected for my precompile directives.  The dropdown in the upper left of the code window did the trick, though.